# How to prove every partition of same cardinality sets has same cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $A$ is a set, and $A$ is partitioned into two ways, $\{A_i\}$ and $\{B_i$} where any $A_1,A_2 \in \{A_i\}$ and $B_1,B_2 \in \{B_i\}$ we have $|A_1|=|A_2|=|B_1|=|B_2|$. Then is that true $|\{A_i\}|=|\{B_i\}|$?

Intuitively, $|\{A_i\}|=|\{B_i\}|=|A|/|A_1|$ where $A_1 \in \{A_i\}$. However it makes sense when it's only in finite case. I can't construct bijection between those two partitions. Help me.

Comment: Do you assume the axiom of choice?

Comment: Sure, I think it needs something like transfinite induction. Otherwise, it will be super-hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find a counterexample even assuming $\{A_i\}$ is infinite.

Let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal. Consider the 1-1 correspondence $f:\omega_1\times\omega_1 \to \omega_1$. Then
$$\{f[\omega_1\times\{\alpha\}]: \alpha <\omega_1\}$$
is a partition of $\omega_1$ with cardinality $\aleph_1$ and all of its elements also have cardinality $\aleph_1$. On the other hand, the collection of sets of the form
$$A_n = \{\omega\cdot\alpha + n : \alpha<\omega_1\}$$
is countable. You can easily check that $|A_n|=\aleph_1$ holds.

Comment: Why ordinal in $\omega_1$ can be decomposed into $\omega \alpha+n$?

Comment: @Maddy Since every ordinal has its unique Cantor normal form.

Answer (score 6):

The statement is not generally true if $A$ is allowed to be infinite; for instance take $A=\Bbb Z$ and (severely abusing notation) $A_{0,1}=\{0,1\}+2\Bbb Z$ and $B_{0,1,2}=\{0,1,2\}+3\Bbb Z$.

As the comment chain suggests, forcing one of the partitions to have infinitely many parts would probably help, at least with AoC. Unfortunately, I can't see how to do the proof.

Comment: I think you read the question wrong?

Comment: @Asaf: That's likely, but I don't see how. I always manage to misread set theory questions even after re-reading them six times.

Comment: You are answering "suppose the partitions have the same size, do the parts have the same size?" and the question is "Assume all the parts have the same size, are the partitions sam size?"

Comment: @Asaf: No, I'm not. I constructed the partitions to have parts with size $|\Bbb Z|$, but the partitions do not have the same size. So this is a counterexample to "parts have same size implies partitions have same size".

Comment: I think i should assume $|\{A_i\}|$ is infinite.

Comment: Ohh, right, I'm reading the answer wrong! Sorry. :-)

Comment: npnp. Feels nice to get it right for once :P

Comment: $\{0,1\}+2\mathbb Z$ etc. would be less abuse of notation

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Ah, yes, it would be nice to have a partition which partitions the set.

Comment: Even simpler: just let $B_0=\{\mathbb Z\}$, so $|\{A_i\}| = 2$ and $|\{B_i\}| = 1$.